# NVM - How to use an NPM version through NVM?

Tags: windows, npm, nvm

I have used NPM for years, but never NVM before. I now find myself in a situation where I need 2 different versions installed, so I uninstalled NodeJS and installed NVM.

If I use `nvm list` I see 3 different versions installed.
If I use `nvm use 16.18.1`, I can see that *nvm* thinks I'm using v16.18.1, but when I type `npm -v` I get `8.19.2`.

I have cloned a repo, I need to install it using 16.18.1. `nvm install` does not do what `npm install` does. So, using nvm, how do I execute npm commands using a specific node version?

I installed NVM. I used nvm to install npm v16.18.1. Now what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your commands with administrator privilege.
In start, type `cmd`, right ckick, run as administrator.
Then type `nvm use [yourVersion]`.
Check if you are using that version
For more https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#usage

`nvm install` only download the version of nvm you want to use and has nothing to do with `npm install`. Read the docs for more.
Once you are using the correct version of node, you can `npm install` in your project as always.

Comment: Ok. I was getting npm is not a valid system command (as if npm wasn't installed). I uninstalled nvm, rebooted, installed nvm, and "npm" is a valid command again. I was also confused about the version numbers between node -v and npm -v. But it is working now. Thank you very much!